# Create and populate new sheets with data from master workbook

Tags: excel, vba, populate

Could someone be kind enough to help an Excel novice with the following problem? I've been stuck on it for too long..

I've got one master workbook (Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU5SC.jpg) with data that I'd like to populate new sheets with in the same workbook. I'd need Excel to automatically create the new sheets based on a template I have (Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/drK6d.jpg). The name of the new sheet should be the offer number (written in red) and I'd need Excel to create that new sheet after I've inserted the offer number. The rest of the data that I need transferred is also written in red in the pics and placed in their intended cells.

Hope it wasn't too confusing. Could all this be done somehow? I'd be more than grateful if anyone took the time to help me out with this! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros to do this activity try using below function,

```
function SplitData()
RowNum  = 12
while DataWorkBook.Sheet1.range("B" & RowNum))=False
     'set wbNewWorkBook = workbooks.Open("TemplatePath\template.xlsx")
     set newSheet = DataWorkBook.sheets("Template").copy
     newSheet.range("A8")=DataWorkBook.sheet1.Range("D" & RowNum)
     RowNum = RowNum + 1
wend
```

Add/Map other cells in the similar way with in the while loop and link it with a button.

Regards
Vel

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Just found out that I need the new sheets to open in the same workbook after all, what changes should I make to the code you provided to make this happen?

Thanks again!